# Solving error: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Small question about globals. I have the following code:

```
counter = 0
class A():
    global counter

    def connect():
        counter += 1
        print("Opening connection",counter)
        # DO STUFF

    def disconnect():
        counter -= 1
        print("Closing connection",counter)
        # DO STUFF
```

Each time I connect or disconnect, I want to know the number of opened connections `counter` (not just for one instance, rather for all of the instances, so it should be static). But when running the code I get:

```
local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment
```

Why is that? Consider that `A()` is located in other file than `main`.

Comment: "global" declaration only works in a function/method.

Comment: you don't need to write lobal counter in the class but you have to do it in the methods

Comment: @Michael Butscher,  I know, in fact i edited, I made a mistake while writing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, `global` declaration only works in a function or a method.

```py
counter = 0
class A():
    def connect():
        global counter
        counter += 1
        print("Opening connection",counter)
        # DO STUFF

    def disconnect():
        global counter
        counter -= 1
        print("Closing connection",counter)
        # DO STUFF
```

Comment: Thank you. If I have two instances of `A()`, they share the counter right?

Comment: Yup. P.S - This comment word limit is irritating.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
counter = 0
class A():

    def connect():
        global counter
        counter += 1
        print("Opening connection",counter)
        # DO STUFF

    def disconnect():
        global counter
        counter -= 1
        print("Closing connection",counter)
        # DO STUFF
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move global counter inside the functions.

Also if you are using multithreading/multiprocessing you should use a semaphore while updating the counter.